# Choosing SMPS, buck regulator or controller

Tags: buck

There are thousands of buck regulators I can choose but I can use some good advices. I need fixed 7...8V output, 10...15V input and 2A maximum. The problem is I can't decide because I need smallest board (components) and high efficiency from 0.1A to 1.5A.

Most converters have high eff. starting from 0.5 or 1A. Others have a lot of components, including push-pull mosfets outside. And finally others are exorbitant as price (I found some from Linear Technology, inductorless, in fact component less but hugh price).

Answer (score 2):

You are interested in optimize the buck regulator in terms of 1)efficiency 2)external component count 3)price
try [TI WEBENCH® Designer](http://ti.com) by using it you can design power supply(get schematics,BOM,samples) and can optimize your design based on foot print,BOM cost,efficiency.
[image: First page- enter your requirements here]

[image: Schematic of the selected design]

Comment: WEBENCH is great, but only does TI based circuits (and the companies that are merged into TI.)

There are other companies, like Maxim, or ST, OKI, or whatever, that also have useful solutions that WEBENCH doesn't design with.

In general, choosing the right regulator is as much art as science, and if it's really important, you might want to try more than one and see which design comes out the best. Also beware that higher switching frequencies can give you faster/better regulation and smaller/cheaper components, but also have significantly more sensitivity to component layout and PCB design.